# Is there a way to edit the animation curve in the graph editor for all axis at the same time?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Is there a way to edit the animation curve in the graph editor for all axis at the same time? I want to create a custom curve for moving from point A to point B, but I do not want to make this custom curve for each X, Y, and Z-axis, but for the move as a whole. Thanks!